# How to log runtime exceptions?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have my log4j configure file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ERROR, DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\~\\website.txt
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

This prints all the trace but, I want to tweak my configs so that I can print `e.printStackTrace()` to my log too.

I can achieve the same by using

```
LOGGER.error("Runtime exception", ex);
```

Can I print the stack trace directly to the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `printStackTrace()` in `java.lang.Throwable` is hard-coded to send output to `System.err` so in short, no you can't configure log4j in any way that would cause calls to `printStackTrace()` to be sent to the file configured in your "file" appender.